# Selective history.back() using Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, browser-history

I have a Backbone app.  I'm using Backbone.history to enable use of the back button.  We have a page (settings) that auto loads a popup requiring input from the user.  If the user chooses cancel, I want to go back to the previous page.  I can do this using window.history.back().

The problem is, if the user went directly to that page (app#settings) from another url (like google) by typing the url into the browser, I want to redirect the user to the home page (app/) rather than going back to google.

I haven't been able to figure out any way to do this.  Backbone.history looks like it store information from the browser's back button, so it has a history even if they just arrived at the app.  I also couldn't find a way to view the previous url.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Wrap the back navigation logic in a method of your own. Perhaps on the router:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    this.routesHit = 0;
    //keep count of number of routes handled by your application
    Backbone.history.on('route', function() { this.routesHit++; }, this);
  },

  back: function() {
    if(this.routesHit > 1) {
      //more than one route hit -> user did not land to current page directly
      window.history.back();
    } else {
      //otherwise go to the home page. Use replaceState if available so
      //the navigation doesn't create an extra history entry
      this.navigate('app/', {trigger:true, replace:true});
    }
  }
});
```

And use the router method to navigate back:

```
appRouter.back();
```

Comment: this approach counts every route including browser back navigation's. let say i am navigating to 3 routes inside my app, then routesHit will be 3. Now using browser back button won't reduce routesHit (rather increases it) and browser will eventually take you out of your app.

Answer (score 3):

I used the same answer from [jevakallio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860461/selective-history-back-using-backbone-js/14861505#14861505), but I had the same problem that commenter Jay Kumar had: The `routesHit` doesn't subtract so hitting `appRouter.back()` enough times will take the user out of the app, so I added 3 lines:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    this.routesHit = 0;
    //keep count of number of routes handled by your application
    Backbone.history.on('route', function() { this.routesHit++; }, this);
  },

  back: function() {
    if(this.routesHit > 1) {
      //more than one route hit -> user did not land to current page directly
      this.routesHit = this.routesHit - 2; //Added line: read below
      window.history.back();
    } else {
      //otherwise go to the home page. Use replaceState if available so
      //the navigation doesn't create an extra history entry
      if(Backbone.history.getFragment() != 'app/') //Added line: read below
        this.routesHit = 0; //Added line: read below
      this.navigate('app/', {trigger:true, replace:true});
    }
  }
});
```

And use the router method to navigate back:

```
appRouter.back();
```

Added lines:

1st one: Subtract 2 from `routesHit`, then when its redirected to the "back" page it'll gain 1 so it's actually like you did just a minus 1.

2nd one: if user is already at "home", there wont be a redirect so don't do anything to `routesHit`.

3rd one: If user is where he started and is being sent back to "home", set `routesHit = 0`, then when redirected to "home" `routesHit` will be 1 again.